# How to remove edges to make a graph bipartite?

Tags: graph, bipartite

I have a graph which may ( or may not ) contain a set of edges that make it bipartite. How can I discover if such a set exists?

[image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=28ama2h&s=5#.Uspc5uLcPu0]

Will removing all edges in a particular level during BFS traversal help?

Answer (score 1):

Since any bipartite graph is also 2-colourable you can use any algorithm that checks for this trait. You could e.g. do it with BFS using a backtracking based algorithm. Generally speaking it could look like this:

Assume if the graph is bipartite the vertexes can be divided into groups A and B. Choose a source vertex, colour it red (group A). Then colour all neighbouring vertices blue (group B), and then those neighbours' neighbours red. If during the colouring process you find a neighbour that has the same colour as the current vertex it is not 2-colourable and thus not bipartite. This might not cover all specifics, but you should get the idea.

Comment: The graph is not bipartite initially. I need to see, if I could remove some edges to make it bipartite

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I get your problem, it wasn't that clear for me with the initial post. You don't have to calculate this, Paul Erdös showed that any graph with e edges always contains a bipartite subgraph of at least e/2 edges. I don't remember where it was published, but you should find this in the internet easily. Also if I remember correctl any cut of a graph is bipartite, so if you want to actually find one you could possibly just take an algorithm that gets the maximum cut.